# OAuth2 with Google "invalid_request" - Spring Boot + React

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have Spring Boot backend and React frontend in which I want to implement OAuth2 with Google. However, I get "invalid_request" error when I want to confirm the login with Google (when I choose an account to login and click on "Continue").

This is the method that creates the request URL:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationController {

@Autowired
    private ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;


@GetMapping("/google")
    public ResponseEntity<String> redirectToGoogle() {
        ClientRegistration clientRegistration = clientRegistrationRepository.findByRegistrationId("google");

        Map<String, Object> additionalParameters = new HashMap<>();
        additionalParameters.put("prompt", "consent");
        additionalParameters.put("access_type", "offline");
        additionalParameters.put("response_type", "code");
        additionalParameters.put("state", generateState());

        OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = authorizationCode()
                .clientId(clientRegistration.getClientId())
                .authorizationUri(clientRegistration.getProviderDetails().getAuthorizationUri())
                .redirectUri(clientRegistration.getRedirectUri())
                .scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email " +
                        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile " +
                        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly " +
                        "openid")
                .additionalParameters(additionalParameters)
                .build();


        String authorizationRequestUri = authorizationRequest.getAuthorizationRequestUri();

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(authorizationRequestUri);
    }

}
```

Then, it is called in the frontend which initiates the OAuth2 flow by redirecting to the Google authentication page:

```
const redirectToGoogle = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await OAuth2Service.getGoogleRedirectUri();

        window.location.href = response.data;
      } catch (error) { 
        console.error('Error initiating OAuth:', error);
      }
    };
```

And here is my callback function:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/login")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class OAuth2Controller {

    @GetMapping("/oauth2/code/google")
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleGoogleCallback(@RequestParam("code") String code) {
        System.out.println(code);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("callback method triggered");
    }

}
```

I have configured the redirect URI correctly in the Google Console and it tries to do the callback but the error is thrown immediately and the callback method is never entered.

This is in my `WebSecurityConfig`, however I doubt that the issue is here:

```
.oauth2Login(oauth2LoginConfigurer ->
                        oauth2LoginConfigurer
                                .successHandler((request, response, authentication) ->
                                        response.setStatus(200))
                                .failureHandler((request, response, exception) -> response.setStatus(401))
                );
```

I have put all the necessary properties in my `application.properties` and I have also configured my `ClientRegistrationRepository` correctly.

I also tried using the Google OAuth 2.0 Playground and I do not see how my request is any different from the expected.

I will be grateful if you can help me.